# Child once removed from parent does not re-appear

Tags: swift, xcode, sprite-kit

I'm making a super simple game where the game creates a random, tappable shape from an array of shapes (shapes in the code block). Once tapped, I call node.removefromparent() on the tapped node and add a new node from the same array to the rootnode via addchild.

Here's my problem: If the random node created is the same as one previously removed, it does not show up. How do I fix this?

Here's the code for the creation function and the removal function:

creation

```
func CreateShape() {

        let shape = shapes.randomElement()!
        shape.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.5)
        shape.colorBlendFactor = 1.0
        shape.color = colors.randomElement() ?? UIColor.systemPink
        shape.name = "figur"
        shape.zPosition = 100
        shape.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: 150)
        shape.physicsBody?.isDynamic = false
        shape.position = CGPoint(x: randomPos().x, y: randomPos().y)
        print(shape)

        addChild(shape)

    }
```

removal:

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

        let touch = touches.first
        let location = touch!.location(in: self)
        let tappedNodes = nodes(at: location)

        guard let tapped = tappedNodes.first else { return }

        if tapped.name == "figur" {

            let fadeOut = SKAction.fadeAlpha(to: 0, duration: 0.5)
            let randomAction = actions.randomElement()!
            let remove = SKAction.removeFromParent()
            let sequence = SKAction.sequence([randomAction, fadeOut, remove])
            sequence.timingMode = .easeInEaseOut

            tapped.run(sequence)

            self.isUserInteractionEnabled = false

            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1.5, execute: {

                self.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
                self.CreateShape()

            })
        }
    }
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you posted the code for `shapes.randomElement()`

Comment: @0x141E This is my array of SKSpritnodes. There's more in there but the character limit does not allow me to post more :)  var shapes: [SKSpriteNode] = [SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "shapes/Arrow"),
                              SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "shapes/bell.fill"),
                              SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "shapes/bolt")]

Comment: do you only get the big when trying to add the same node as the one that was tapped? Could it be a timing error and adding the node before the removeFromParent (although this should also give an error). What happens if you duplicate the shape before adding it if the same shape is selected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting the alpha to 0, but you never reset it.

```
func CreateShape() {

        let shape = shapes.randomElement()!
        shape.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.5)
        shape.colorBlendFactor = 1.0
        shape.color = colors.randomElement() ?? UIColor.systemPink
        shape.name = "figur"
        shape.zPosition = 100
        shape.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: 150)
        shape.physicsBody?.isDynamic = false
        shape.position = CGPoint(x: randomPos().x, y: randomPos().y)
        shape.alpha = 1.0 //<-----insert here
        print(shape)


        addChild(shape)

    }
```

Comment: Yep, that was it. Thanks! PS: thank you everyone else as well!!

Comment: No problem, very easy to miss